# Doctrine2 duplicate entries for key stops execution

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, duplicates

I am running a script in Symfony2/Doctrine2 project.

And I receive the Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\UniqueConstraintViolationException exception.

```
An exception occurred while executing 
'INSERT INTO user (name, created_at) VALUES (?, ?)' 
with params ["Gaurav" "2016-07-31 17:10:54"]:               

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 
1062 Duplicate entry 'Gaurav' for key 'UNIQ_8C9F36105E237E06'
```

Any idea, how I can avoid this?

I have been using Repository findByOne() and then updating the record. It still generates an SQL query.

I found the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3967226/checking-for-duplicate-keys-with-doctrine-2). But I am not sure, if this is necessary.

Please advise.

Comment: How are you doing your 'updates'?  Getting an INSERT from and update seems strange.  I suspect a batch operation of some sort.

Comment: @Cerad Yes. Its a kinda batch operation, as its a loop reading input from file.

Answer (score 0):

Check how did you define db schema. This exception tells you that you tried to insert duplicate value for column which is defined as unique.

Comment: Yes. But it should not reach the db layer if I get the record from repository and try to update the managed entity.