# How to update an unique entity field with Symfony 4 form

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony4

I’m updating my user entity. It’s a unique entity defined on it's unique email.
Unfortunately, when updating my entity, I’m triggering a validation error due to this email unique validation rule.

I’ve been trying to pass the $user to the form to make sure it considers it as a user update but no luck.

It’s an Ajax form.

Any idea how to work around this please?

User entity

```
class User implements UserInterface, \Serializable
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string $email
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=254, nullable=false)
 * @Assert\Email()
 * @Assert\NotBlank
 * @AcmeAssert\UniqueEmail
 */
private $email;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=25, nullable=true)
 */
private $username;
// and so on
```

My controller:

```
/**
 * @Route("/profile", name="profile")
*/
public function profile()
{
    $user = $this->getUser();
    $formAccount = $this->updateUserAccountForm( $user );

    return $this->render('platform/user/profile.html.twig',
        array(
            'user' => $user,
            'form_account' => $formAccount->createView()
        )
    );
}

/**
 * @Route("/profile/updateAccount", name="updateUserAccount", methods={"POST"})
 */
public function updateUserAccount(Request $request, UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncode)
{
    if (!$request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        return new JsonResponse(array('message' => 'Forbidden'), 400);
    }

    // Build The Form
    $user = $this->getUser();

    $form = $this->updateUserAccountForm($user);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $user_form = $form->getData();

        // Check if the password is = to DB
        $current_password = $passwordEncoder->encodePassword($user, $user_form->getPlainPassword());

        if($user->getPassword() != $current_password){
            return new JsonResponse(['error' => 'wrong password!']);
        }

        // Encode the password (We could also do this via Doctrine listener)
        $password = $passwordEncoder->encodePassword($user_form, $user_form->getPlainPassword());
        $user_form->setPassword($password);

        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $entityManager->merge($user_form);
        $entityManager->flush();

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($user_form);
//            $em->flush();

        return new JsonResponse(array('message' => 'Success!'), 200);
    }

    $errors = [];
    foreach ($form->getErrors(true, true) as $formError) {
        $errors[] = $formError->getMessage();
    }
    $errors['userid'] = $user->getId();
    $errors['user'] = $user->getUsername();
    return new JsonResponse($errors);
}

/**
 * Creates a form to update user account.
 *
 * @param User $entity The entity
 *
 * @return \Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface The form
 */
private function updateUserAccountForm(User $user)
{
    $form = $this->createForm( AccountType::class, $user,
        array(
            'action' => $this->generateUrl('updateUserAccount'),
            'method' => 'POST',
        ));

    return $form;
}
```

And the AccountType.php

```
class AccountType extends AbstractType
{
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('username', TextType::class)
        ->add('email', EmailType::class, array(
            'required' => true,
            'constraints' => array(
                new NotBlank(),
            )))
        ->add('password', PasswordType::class, array(
            'required' => true
            ))
        ->add('plainPassword', RepeatedType::class, array(
            'type' => PasswordType::class,
            'invalid_message' => 'The new password fields must match.',
            'required' => false,
            'first_options'  => array('label' => 'New Password'),
            'second_options' => array('label' => 'Confirm New Password')
        ))
        ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Save ->'));
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        // enable/disable CSRF protection for this form
        'csrf_protection' => true,
        // the name of the hidden HTML field that stores the token
        'csrf_field_name' => '_token',
        // an arbitrary string used to generate the value of the token
        // using a different string for each form improves its security
        'csrf_token_id'   => 'reset_item',
        'data_class' => User::class
    ));
}
}
```

The ajax call do return a form serialized. The form has been created in the profile function and works well. I’m getting a form error message when calling '$form->isValid()’

I’ve been trying everything to pass the $user in the form type to make Symfony understand it’s based on a pre-existing user. but no luck.

Any help is appreciated thanks!

EDIT: Here is my custom UniqueEmail Validator class:

```
class UniqueEmailValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{
    /**
     * @var EntityManager
     */
    protected $em;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
    {
        $this->em = $entityManager;
    }

    public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint)
    {
        // Do we have a pre registered user in DB from email form landing page?
        $userRepository = $this->em->getRepository(User::class);
        $existingUser = $userRepository->findOneByEmail($value);

        if ($existingUser && $existingUser->getIsActive()) {
            $this->context->buildViolation($constraint->message)
                ->setParameter('{{ string }}', $value)
                ->addViolation();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: UniqueEmail is a custom constraint validation right? Can you show the code of this constraint validation? Also, the error displayed, please.

Comment: You maybe need to use a UniqueConstraintViolationException in a try/catch , I suggest you to read this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3967226/checking-for-duplicate-keys-with-doctrine-2

Comment: @FranckGamess thanks for your comment, I’ve edit my question posting the UniqueEmailValidator.php file. The messages triggered is the one I set up in UniqueEmail.php in the same validator folder.

Comment: @pbenard Thanks, I understand this scenario is when invoking flush(). Would that work with the form validation ?

Comment: No I don't think, you just have to wrap the flush inside a try\catch, if error is catch, you add Manually an error, with $form->addError, and return the form as this.

Comment: @pbenard thank you!

Answer (score 2):

From what I see, when you submit the form the **UniqueEmail** constraint you set on the **email** field try to validate the submitted value with the rule you defined.
Let's say you want to update the **username** only, the form will be sent with the current value of the **email field** stored in the database. And of course, it will trigger a validation error.

Generally, it is better to put a unique constraint on the **email** column in your **user** table. So you will be able to update properly your **User** entity even if you don't modify the **email** field. And also you won't be able to create a new user in the database having the same email as an existing user. I guess this is what you want.

Doctrine can help you to achieve this.

With [@UniqueConstraint](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/annotations-reference.html#uniqueconstraint) on the entity level:

```
<?php
/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="user_table",uniqueConstraints= {@UniqueConstraint(name="search_idx", columns={"email"})})
 */
class User implements UserInterface, \Serializable
{
}
```

With [@Column](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/annotations-reference.html#column) on the field level with **unique** attribute(I prefer this one but depends on the case):

```
/**
 * @var string $email
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=32, unique=true, nullable=false)
 * @Assert\Email()
 * @Assert\NotBlank
 */
private $email;
```

Just take a look and try to see if it solves your issue.